# Battery management system for BR50?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, charger, bms

I have a motorolla Razr v3I but unfortunately, the battery does not charge. I suspect it it due to a non compatible charger.
I decided i could create a diy external unti like a camera battery charger to charge thes batteries.

The question is

1. battery has 4 terminals, 2 with +,- which are obvious. There are 2 unmarked terminals. What's the use of those terminals?

2)how to proceed with a BMS?

[image: An image of the battery. There is nothing on the front side.]

[image]

Comment: If you don't know what you're doing, I strongly suggest you don't mess with lithium ion batteries. If you insist on doing so anyway, look for as foolproof a charger IC as you can find, and follow every recommendation on the datasheet to the letter.

Comment: Also be  aware that there is a difference between a BMS and a charger. You cannot charge a battery with a BMS alone.

Comment: @HearthI know I can use things like the TP4056 but I don't think this as direct as pluging the charger terminals to the battery. Batteries are dangerous that's why I asked what the other terminals do. I'm guessing they are related to balance terminal?